# Problem with traversing WPF element tree

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, elementtree

I have a `ListBox` data bound to the collection of my `PersonCollection` class. Next, I have defined a data template for objects of type `Person`, consisted of a `DockPanel` which contains a `TextBlock` for a person's name and a `Button` to remove the person from the list. It looks very nice all together.

The problem I am facing is that I am unable to reach the selected item (and delete it) in the list box when I click the button defined in the data template. Here's the handler of the button:

```
private void RemovePersonButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button clickedButton = (Button)e.Source;
    DockPanel buttonPanel = (DockPanel)clickedButton.Parent;
    Control control = (Control)button.Parent;
}
```

The last created object `control` is `null`, i.e. I cannot progress further up the element tree, so I cannot reach the list and its `SelectedItem`. Important thing to note here is that cannot simply go with getting the selected item from the list by calling it, because I have more than one list in the window and all those lists implement the same data template, i.e. share the same event handler for the delete button.

I would appreciate all the help I could get. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly I think you'll be able to get the Person from the Button's DataContext

```
private void RemovePersonButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    Button clickedButton = (Button)e.Source; 
    Person selectedItem = clickedButton.DataContext as Person;
    if (selectedItem != null)
    {
        PersonCollection.Remove(selectedItem);
    }
}
```

Another way is to find the ListBox in the VisualTree

```
private void RemovePersonButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    Button clickedButton = (Button)e.Source; 
    ListBox listBoxParent = GetVisualParent<ListBox>(clickedButton );
    Person selectedItem = listBoxParent.SelectedItem as Person;
    //...
}

public T GetVisualParent<T>(object childObject) where T : Visual
{
    DependencyObject child = childObject as DependencyObject;
    while ((child != null) && !(child is T))
    {
        child = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
    }
    return child as T;
}
```

Comment: Correct! Very good. I was unaware of the `DataContext` property. For what is worth, I was able to find my way through the element tree by calling `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(DependencyObject reference)` method, but this is a much better solution! Thank you.

Comment: I prefer the first solution. Thanks for posting!

Comment: @Boris: Sure thing! Yes, the first version is better for sure :) Added the second one because I wasn't sure if you needed the corresponding ListBox for something

Answer (score 0):

You might try using [VisualTreeHelper.GetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getparent.aspx) to walk the visual tree, rather than relying on the Logical Parent.

That said, you might consider whether you can wrap your Person in a PersonItem class, with additional context information so that the PersonItem knows how to remove the Person from the list.  I'll sometimes use this pattern and I wrote an EncapsulatingCollection class that automatically instantiates wrapper objects based on the changes in a monitored ObservableCollection.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Wrapping the Person is a clever idea, however, the solution provided by Meleak is basically all I need at the moment. Cheers.